# Any tools or techniques to enrich NetBeans code generation (web services)?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, code-generation, jax-ws

I'm working on a project that involves the creation of numerous web services. Top-down/contract-first and model-driven design strategies are utilized (WSDL -> codegen).  NetBeans (6.7) + JAX-WS + GlassFish comprise the chosen tooling stack.  The web services will be EJBs deployed as Composite Applications in the Glassfish JBI container.

We have a need to implement systemic qualities to the web service implementtation classes, such as overriding `toString` implementations, adding logging, even applying a Template method pattern to the implementation classes.

Since the NetBeans/JAX-WS does not provide the means to inject our customizations into its code generation process, I do not see a way to accomplish what I want to do short of modifying the generated classes manually.  Top-down, yes; model-driven, not anymore.  And doing so would have significant maintenance implications for the project, as the web services may be periodically revised.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can accomplish what I need given the tools I have to work with?  Perhaps a plugin that integrates AOP with JAX-WS codegen?  A magic @DoNotClobber annotation supported by another codegen to preserve developer-user code?

And, if I had the opportunity to use an Eclipse-based tool set, would the grass be greener?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research.  It looks like JAX-WS/JAXB allows for augmenting its code generation, but not to the extend that I need.

The Eclipse Modeling Framework recognizes the value of merging regeneration, though.  And apparently EMF is usable in non-Eclipse development environments.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the Templates for JAX-WS are customizable.  You should be able to find them in the Template Manager; use the Templates item of the Tools menu to open this manager.

Many of the managed templates can be customized by the using the 'Open in Editor' button.

[This tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html) covers a lot of information about templates in NetBeans.  It may be a bit too much for your immediate need, but it does have some useful screen shots and the like.